# Should Data Definition Language be a synonym of DDL?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

At the moment the tag [data-definition-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-definition-language) doesn't have a wiki and only 6 questions.

The tag [ddl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ddl) does exist as well, has 618 questions and a fine wiki.

I personally find Data-Definition-Language more clear than DDL but given the current state, shouldn't the two be synomized?

And if so, which one should be the master?

Comment: I made [ddl] the master tag, and synonymized and merged them so future uses of [data-definition-language] will automatically be converted.